# OctomapBinary.h: No such file or directory

Tags: octomap, rosmake, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['octomap_server']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/turtlebot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130324-200938
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['octomap_server'] to:
['octomap_server']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkinive 0/58 Complete ]
No Makefile in package catkin
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
No Makefile in package genmsg
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
No Makefile in package rosgraph
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
No Makefile in package cpp_common
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
No Makefile in package genpy
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
No Makefile in package rospack
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
No Makefile in package genlisp
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
No Makefile in package gencpp
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
No Makefile in package rostime
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
No Makefile in package message_generation
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
No Makefile in package roscpp_traits
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
No Makefile in package rosunit
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp3/58 Complete ]
No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam
No Makefile in package rosparam
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> flann [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
No Makefile in package rosclean
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> angles [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster
No Makefile in package rosmaster
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< flann ROS_NOBUILD in package flann
No Makefile in package flann
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> console_bridge [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
No Makefile in package angles
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
No Makefile in package message_runtime
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< console_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package console_bridge
No Makefile in package console_bridge
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> class_loader [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib
No Makefile in package smclib
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< class_loader ROS_NOBUILD in package class_loader
No Makefile in package class_loader
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_srvs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_srvs
No Makefile in package std_srvs
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bond [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
No Makefile in package pluginlib
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond
No Makefile in package bond
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< visualization_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package visualization_msgs
No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pcl_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
No Makefile in package rosout
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nav_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package nav_msgs
No Makefile in package nav_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package actionlib_msgs
No Makefile in package actionlib_msgs
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pcl_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_msgs
No Makefile in package pcl_msgs
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp
No Makefile in package bondcpp
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> trajectory_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
No Makefile in package roslaunch
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< trajectory_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package trajectory_msgs
No Makefile in package trajectory_msgs
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet
No Makefile in package nodelet
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters]
No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tf [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
No Makefile in package tf
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools
No Makefile in package topic_tools
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> arm_navigation_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag
No Makefile in package rosbag
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< arm_navigation_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package arm_navigation_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl
No Makefile in package pcl
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> octomap_ros [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
No Makefile in package rosmsg
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice Complete ]
No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
No Makefile in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
No Makefile in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros
No Makefile in package pcl_ros
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linestomap_ros: 90.6 sec ]       [ 1 Active 56/58 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build' make[3]: Entering directory` /home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build' [  0%] [  0%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_cpp [  0%] Built target ROSBUILD_gensrv_lisp Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_lisp make[3]: Entering directory` /home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build'
[  0%] Built target ROSBUILD_gensrv_cpp
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build' [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg make[3]: Entering directory` /home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build'
[  0%] Built target rospack_gensrv
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build' make[3]: Entering directory` /home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build' make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build' [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_all [  0%] [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile Built target rospack_gensrv_all make[3]: Entering directory` /home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build' make[3]: Entering directory` /home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build'
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/octomap_ros.dir/src/conversions.cpp.o
In file included from /home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/src/conversions.cpp:40:0:
/home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/include/octomap_ros/conversions.h:44:40: fatal error: octomap_msgs/OctomapBinary.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/octomap_ros.dir/src/conversions.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/octomap_ros.dir/all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/turtlebot/alufr-ros-pkg-read-only/octomap_stacks/octomap_ros/build'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package octomap_ros written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/turtlebot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130324-200938/octomap_ros/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< octomap_ros [FAIL] [ 90.59 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package octomap_ros.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 57 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/turtlebot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130324-200938

Please help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59028/octomapbinary.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on 2013-03-24**:
This website http://www.ros.org/wiki/octomap_mapping

and I downloaded

svn checkout http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ alufr-ros-pkg-read-only

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2013-03-25**:
octomap_msgs/OctomapBinary.h: No such file or directory <-- does this file actually exist in that directory? Is the casing correct? (it's not octomapbinary.h, is it?).

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-03-25**:
Which ROS version are you using?

**Comment by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on 2013-03-25**:
ROS version is 1.9.42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a reason you install octomap_mapping from source, and not the binary packages?

You can install them pre-compiled with all dependencies by running `sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping` (fuerte) or `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-octomap-mapping` (groovy).

It seems to me that you are either missing a dependency (octomap_msgs) in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, or mixing different ROS versions. OctomapBinary.h only exists for fuerte.

If you need a source compile, then you also need to manually download and compile the dependencies, most notably the packages octomap_ros and octomap_msgs. Fuerte versions are at http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/octomap_stacks/ and
Groovy versions here:
https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_msgs
https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_ros

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on 2013-03-25**:
Problem is solved   Thanks All